# PHP function confusion

Tags: php

I have the following scenario (simplified):

```
function changeFruit($fruit) {
    changeAgain($fruit);

}

function changeAgain($fruit) {
     $fruit = "Orange";
}

MAIN:

$fruit = "Apple";
changeFruit($fruit);
echo $fruit // Will show up as "Apple", How do I get it to show up as "Orange"??
```

**EDIT: FORGOT TO ADD. THE SCENARIO CANNOT USE RETURN STATEMENTS - JUST &$variable**

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: To the person who downvoted the question, you should seriously go back and check your very first code.

Comment: And also, good practice to leave a comment if you downvote a question, to help improve the question)

Comment: Anax: It wasn't me who downvoted you, but it seems that you haven't read much of the manual. Try this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Hey I don't want to start a flame war here.. the issue DID NOT involve return statements.. I wanted more information on &$variable. I apologize it was late and a poorly written question and description, but my question's intent was not entirely trivial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you pass something that is not an object to a function in PHP, php makes a copy of that to use within the function.

To make it not use a copy, you need to tell PHP you are passing a reference.

This is done with the & operator

```
function changeFruit(&$fruit) {
    changeAgain($fruit);

}

function changeAgain(&$fruit) {
     $fruit = "Orange";
}

$fruit = "Apple";
changeFruit($fruit);
echo $fruit;
```

It would be more sensible, and better practice, to use return values of the functions (as this makes things easier to read)

```
function changeFruit($fruit) {
    return changeAgain($fruit);
}

function changeAgain($fruit) {
     // do something more interesting with$fruit here
     $fruit = "Orange";
     return $fruit;
}

$fruit = "Apple";
$fruit = changeFruit($fruit);
echo $fruit
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into the question a little more. I forgot to add, that I can't return values!

Comment: I was about to write exactly this. Entirely correct and very complete. Clean answer and clear examples!

Comment: Thanks Paul - I tend to only answer if I'm not going to be giving one liners, and there's something I can go into in detail regarding :D

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeFruit($fruit) {
    return changeAgain($fruit);

}

function changeAgain($fruit) {
     return $fruit = "Orange";
}

MAIN:

$fruit = "Apple";
$fruit = changeFruit($fruit);
echo $fruit;
```

Hope that helps!

Note: the return from the changeAgain function and overwriting $fruit = changeFruit($fruit);

Comment: changeFruit also needs to return

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the values from your functions. Try this:

```
function changeFruit($fruit) {
    return changeAgain($fruit);

}

function changeAgain($fruit) {
     $fruit = "Orange";
     return $fruit;
}

MAIN:

$fruit = "Apple";
$fruit = changeFruit($fruit);
```